# TypeScript error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<string>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, arguments, state

I have a string type state:

```
const [name, setName] = React.useState<string>("");
```

And a validate length function that I'm having trouble with the second parameter 'value', with the intention of React setState type:

```
const validateStringLength = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, value: React.SetStateAction<string>) => {
    if (e.currentTarget.value.length <= 47) {
      setName(e.currentTarget.value);
    }
  };
```

Here is my Input:

```
<Input
  onChange={(e) => validateStringLength(e.target.value, setName(name)}
  value={name}
/>
```

Here is my error:

[image]

Thank you all.

Comment: Hello, Badal. I've just left the value there with the intention of show that this is a normal input. I'll remove, next times. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //value type changes
   const validateStringLength = (
        e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>,
        value: **React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>**
      ) => {
        if (e.currentTarget.value.length <= 47) {
          value(e.currentTarget.value);
        }
      }

     //setName doesn't receive parameters
     <Input
        onChange={(e) => validateStringLength(e, setName)}
        value={name}
     />
```